# how to unlock a vagrant machine while it is being provisioned

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

Our vagrant box takes ~1h to provision thus when `vagrant up` is run for the first time, at the very end of provisioning process I would like to package the box to an image in a local folder so it can be used as a base box next time it needs to be rebuilt. I'm using vagrant-triggers plugin to place the code right at the end of :up process.

Relevant (shortened) Vagrantfile:

```
pre_built_box_file_name = 'image.vagrant'
pre_built_box_path      = 'file://' + File.join(Dir.pwd, pre_built_box_file_name)
pre_built_box_exists    = File.file?(pre_built_box_path)
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box     = 'ubuntu/trusty64'
  config.vm.box_url = pre_built_box_path if pre_built_box_exists
  config.trigger.after :up do
    if not pre_built_box_exists
      system("echo 'Building gett vagrant image for re-use...'; vagrant halt; vagrant package --output #{pre_built_box_file_name}; vagrant up;")
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that vagrant locks the machine while the current (`vagrant up`) process is running:

```
An action 'halt' was attempted on the machine 'gett',
but another process is already executing an action on the machine.
Vagrant locks each machine for access by only one process at a time.
Please wait until the other Vagrant process finishes modifying this
machine, then try again.
```

I understand the dangers of two processes provisioning or modifying the machine at one given time, but this is a special case where I'm certain the provisioning has completed.

How can I manually "unlock" vagrant machine during provisioning so I can run `vagrant halt; vagrant package; vagrant up;` from within `config.trigger.after :up`?

Or is there at least a way to start `vagrant up` without locking the machine?

Comment: Why not just `vagrant up && vagrant halt && vagrant package && vagrant up` from the command line?

Comment: Thought a plain `vagrant up` would've taken care of  `vagrant box add ...` or `vagrant box remove ... && vagrant box add ...` in case `image.vagrant` file was removed to be re-built. Maybe I'm just overcomplicating things here.

Comment: `ps aux | grep "vagrant"` copy PID of process and then `kill -9 <PID>`

Answer (score 3):

#### vagrant

This issue has been fixed in [GH #3664](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3664) (2015). If this still happening, probably it's related to plugins (such as AWS). So try without plugins.

#### vagrant-aws

If you're using AWS, then follow this bug/feature report: [#428 - Unable to ssh into instance during provisioning](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/pull/457), which is currently pending.

However there is a pull request which fixes the issue:

- [Allow status and ssh to run without a lock #457](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/pull/457/files)

So apply the fix manually, or waits until it's fixed in the next release.

---

In case you've got this error related to machines which aren't valid, then try running the `vagrant global-status --prune` command.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the effort, but as you can see in the question, I needed a way to unlock the machine during `vagrant up`. Unrelated to AWS, `vagrant ssh` or `vagrant status`.

Comment: The first issue is related to vagrant it-self and sounds like it's fixed, the second part is just in-case you're using aws.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a bit more of a hack than a solution, but I'd rather a hack than nothing.

I ran into this issue and nothing that was suggested here was working for me. Even though this is 6 years old, it's what came up on a google (along with precious little else), I thought I'd share what solved it for me in case anyone else lands here.

#### My Setup

---

I'm using vagrant with `ansible-local` provisioner on a local virtualbox VM, which provisions remote AWS EC2 instances. (i.e. the ansible-local runs on the virtualbox instance, vagrant provisions the virtualbox instance, ansible handles the cloud). This setup is largely because my host OS is Windows and it's a little easier to take Microsoft out of the equation on this one.

#### My Mistake

---

Ran an ansible `shell` task with a command that doesn't terminate without user input (and did not run it with the `&` to run in the background).

#### My Frustration

---

Even in the linux subsystem, trying a `ps aux | grep ruby` or `ps aux | grep vagrant` was unhelpful because the PID would change every time. Probably a reason for this, likely has something to do with how the subsystem works, but I don't know what that reason is.

#### My Solution

---

Just kill the AWS EC2 instances manually. In the console, in the CLI, pick your flavor. Your terminal where you were running `vagrant provision` or `vagrant up` should then finally complete and spit out the summary output, even if you `ctrl + C`'d out of the command.

Hoping this helps someone!